# jquery timepicker value always invalid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, timepicker

I'm using unobtrusive validation on my view, and applying a jquery-ui [timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) to a textbox.

If I pick a proper hour and minute value in the picker, the unobtrusive validation is not triggered.  However, if I tab through my fields, after entering and leaving the timepicker textbox, it is highlights red.  The input-validation message says that my control "must have a valid date."

I know that the TimePicker is part of the DatePicker, however it is looking like the unobtrusive JS thinks this is a DatePicker.

Is there a way I can disable the validation for this control only?  Or perhaps make an adjustment so the value is not marked as invalid?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is this not a real question??????  I am very clear in describing what I am using, what is happening, and asking for help with the solution.